# app.yaml apparently not redirecting correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, yaml

I've been trying to set up a basic Wordpress site with Google App Engine's new PHP SDK, following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress).

From what I understand, `app.yaml` is where the process kicks off and should work similar to `.htaccess` (re routing).

Google instruct you to drop your wordpress files into a wordpress folder, so your directory structure looks like this:

```
.
    ├── app.yaml
    ├── cron.yaml
    ├── php.ini
    └── wordpress
        ├── index.php
        ├── license.txt
        ├── readme.html
        └── (etc)
```

So their template `app.yaml` should work, including the following lines:

```
- url: /wp-cron.php
  script: wordpress/wp-cron.php
  login: admin

- url: /xmlrpc.php
  script: wordpress/xmlrpc.php

- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: wordpress/index.php
```

But **`localhost:8080` gives me my app folder's directory structure, instead of the anticipated `wordpress/index.php.`**  I tried this as well:

```
- url: /.*
  script: wordpress/index.php
```

Any ideas?

Note: I verified that `wordpress/index.php` exists, by the way.

Comment: As a quick fix, I moved the wordpress contents to the root and changed the YAML. So it must need an index.php in the root or something. Still would be curious to know what's up, so I'll leave this question posted.

Comment: What else do you have in your app.yaml? I'm using those same lines and its working fine. You could have a conflicting statement.

Comment: @MorganO'Neal, besides the attempt at `url: /.*`, I have the exact same contents as those found on: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress    It doesn't work even with the default app.yaml template (for me).

Comment: did you create an php.ini as instructed in wp on app engine article?

Comment: Today your structure in problem worked for my wordpress..!! instead of answers.

Answer (score 0):

GAE's dev_appserver will never list the directory structure. Sounds like you might be hitting some other web server running on your localhost?